# How to find a pair of array elements whose difference is smaller than the average difference?

Tags: algorithms, arrays, searching

How to find a pair of indices $1\le i \le n$,$1\le j \le n$, $i\neq j$ in array $A[1..n]$ such that $0\le A[i]-A[j]\le\frac{max(A)-min(A)}{n-1}$ in $\Theta(n)$ time? `max(A)` is the max number in the array while `min(A)` is the min number.

Let $avg=\frac{max(A)-min(A)}{n-1}$. If we sort the array $A$ and calculate the differences of adjacent members then $avg$ is the average difference.

I feel like the question has to do with order statistics (select algorithm) but I don't quite know how exactly.

Comment: Sorting is already $O(nlog(n))$.

Comment: @fade2black  I think there's another solution which doesn't rely on sorting

Comment: Are numbers bounded?

Comment: @rus9384 if you mean that the numbers are within a given range, then no we're not given any range

Comment: @rus9384 if we call `select` algorithm (p.216 CLRS) on the array we can find out the median element in $\Theta(n)$ expected time (although the problem doesn't state that expected time is allowed). Then wouldn't those elements $i,j$ be any elements to the left of the median? (because `select` uses `partition` routine which shuffles every element lesser than the partition to the left)

Comment: Can you credit the source where you encountered this problem?  Also, what makes you think there's another solution that doesn't rely on sorting?  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @D.W. this is an exercise that came from my class which says that the problem can solved in linear time. I can really credit it to anyone. I already had a similar discussion with Raphael but the comments are deleted by now.

Comment: Of course, but currently I can't solve it by myself. So in this case stack exchange is an amazing community where one can get help. The first words of the description of cs stack say "for students" so it's only natural that students like me will be asking questions here a lot of them probably related to homework. And I've noticed a lot of times in this specific community this is not met with understanding, in stark contrast to for example math stack exchange. So for almost every question I start here I need to hold these discussions with moderators which is a shame I think.

Comment: This is not to say that I don't appreciate your answer and comments related to the actual problem.

Comment: https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1151/755

Answer (score 0):

Hint: to build intuition, suppose I told you that you want to find a pair of elements that differ by at most $1000$.  Can you think of any way to find such a pair of elements?  Would looking at the decimal representation of the numbers help?  Could you characterize what their decimal representation would have to look like?

Comment: Does your solution result in linear time complexity? I think I know the solution to the problem if sorting is involved: we sort the numbers, the numbers to the left of the median of the sorted array should satisfy the condition. But this results in $\Theta(n\log n)$ complexity

Comment: @Yos, try it and find out!

Comment: I don't know how it helps since even sorting for array which has it's elements bounded can be done in linear time.

Comment: @rus9384, in this case the elements aren't bounded, so you can't necessarily sort in linear time (for instance, counting sort doesn't run in linear time) -- but there are other ways to solve this without sorting.